# pthread.h not found in Cygwin

Tags: c++, makefile, cygwin

I've been trying to install a third-party library [PicklingTools](http://www.picklingtools.com/) into my windows environment and need to build it using `Makefile.Linux`. I'm using `make` from Cygwin, version 4.3 and `g++` version 9.2.0.

My `Makefile.Linux` is as follows:

```
CC = g++
# CC = icc     # Intel seems to work

## With g++ --version==4.4.x, you may need -fno-strict-aliasing to get rid 
## of some annoying warnings when you compile with -O2 or above

# *****CAREFUL! g++ 4.5.1 20100924 DOES NOT WORK with Ptools and -O.  You must
# compile without optimization for that compiler to work

OC = ./opencontainers_1_8_5
OCINC = $(OC)/include

CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -fpic -O -fno-strict-aliasing -DLINUX_ -DOC_NEW_STYLE_INCLUDES -Wno-deprecated -I$(OCINC) -pthread -D_REENTRANT

## How to build with OCString
##CFLAGS = -Wall -O4 -DLINUX_ -DOC_USE_OC_STRING -DOC_USE_OC_EXCEPTIONS -DOC_ONLY_NEEDED_STL -DOC_NEW_STYLE_INCLUDES -Wno-deprecated -I$(OCINC) 

###### CFLAGS = -Wall -O4 -DLINUX_-DOC_NEW_STYLE_INCLUDES -Wno-deprecated -I$(OCINC) 


CCFLAGS = -pthread $(CFLAGS)

COM_OBJS = m2pythontools.o valpython.o midassocket.o valprotocol2.o m2ser.o m2streamdataenc.o m2convertrep.o timeconv.o fdtools.o
OBJS = midastalker_ex.o midastalker_ex2.o httpclient_ex.o httpserver_ex.o $(COM_OBJS) load.o save.o sharedmemory.o 

all: midasyeller_ex midastalker_ex midastalker_ex2 httpclient_ex midasserver_ex permutation_server permutation_client load save opal2dict dict2opal opaltest midasyeller_ex midaslistener_ex p2_test valgetopt_ex sharedmem_test ready_test xmlload_test xmlload_ex xmldump_test xmldump_ex speed_test pickleloader_test chooseser_test xml2dict dict2xml serverside_ex clientside_ex middleside_ex

.cc.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

libptools.so : $(COM_OBJS) 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) -shared -o libptools.so

midasserver_ex : $(COM_OBJS) midasserver_ex.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) midasserver_ex.o -pthread -o midasserver_ex

httpclient_ex : $(COM_OBJS) httpclient_ex.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) httpclient_ex.o -pthread -o httpclient_ex

httpserver_ex : $(COM_OBJS) httpserver_ex.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) httpserver_ex.o -pthread -o httpserver_ex

midasyeller_ex : $(COM_OBJS) midasyeller_ex.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) midasyeller_ex.o -pthread -o midasyeller_ex

midaslistener_ex : $(COM_OBJS) midaslistener_ex.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) midaslistener_ex.o -pthread -o midaslistener_ex

permutation_server : $(COM_OBJS) permutation_server.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) permutation_server.o -pthread -o permutation_server

permutation_client : $(COM_OBJS) permutation_client.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) permutation_client.o -pthread -o permutation_client

midastalker_ex :$(COM_OBJS) midastalker_ex.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) midastalker_ex.o -o midastalker_ex

midastalker_ex2 :$(COM_OBJS) midastalker_ex2.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) midastalker_ex2.o -o midastalker_ex2

load = load

$(load) : $(COM_OBJS) load.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) load.o -o load

serverside_ex : $(COM_OBJS) sharedmem.o shmboot.o serverside_ex.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) sharedmem.o shmboot.o -lrt serverside_ex.o -o serverside_ex 

middleside_ex : $(COM_OBJS) middleside_ex.o sharedmem.o shmboot.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) sharedmem.o shmboot.o -l rt middleside_ex.o -o middleside_ex 

clientside_ex : $(COM_OBJS) clientside_ex.o sharedmem.o shmboot.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) sharedmem.o shmboot.o -lrt clientside_ex.o -o clientside_ex 

samplehttpserver_ex : $(COM_OBJS) samplehttpserver_ex.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) samplehttpserver_ex.o -o samplehttpserver_ex

save : $(COM_OBJS) save.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) save.o -o save

opal2dict : $(COM_OBJS) opal2dict.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) opal2dict.o -o opal2dict

opaltest : $(COM_OBJS) opaltest.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) opaltest.o -o opaltest

ready_test : $(COM_OBJS) ready_test.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) ready_test.o -o ready_test

chooseser_test : $(COM_OBJS) chooseser_test.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) chooseser_test.o -o chooseser_test

dict2opal : $(COM_OBJS) dict2opal.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) dict2opal.o -o dict2opal

pickleloader_test :  $(COM_OBJS) pickleloader_test.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) pickleloader_test.o -o pickleloader_test -lrt

xmldump_test :  $(COM_OBJS) xmldump_test.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) xmldump_test.o -o xmldump_test -lrt

xmldump_ex :  $(COM_OBJS) xmldump_ex.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) xmldump_ex.o -o xmldump_ex -lrt

xmlload_test :  $(COM_OBJS) xmlload_test.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) xmlload_test.o -o xmlload_test -lrt

xmlload_ex :  $(COM_OBJS) xmlload_ex.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) xmlload_ex.o -o xmlload_ex -lrt

xml2dict :  $(COM_OBJS) xml2dict.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) xml2dict.o -o xml2dict -lrt

dict2xml :  $(COM_OBJS) dict2xml.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) dict2xml.o -o dict2xml -lrt
 
speed_test :  $(COM_OBJS) speed_test.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) speed_test.o -o speed_test -lrt

p2_test :  $(COM_OBJS) p2_test.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) p2_test.o -o p2_test -lrt

valgetopt_ex :  $(COM_OBJS) valgetopt_ex.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) valgetopt_ex.o -o valgetopt_ex

json_ex :  $(COM_OBJS) json_ex.o 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) json_ex.o -o json_ex

# Only the tests that REALLY uses UNIX shared memory need the -lrt
sharedmem_test :  $(COM_OBJS) sharedmem_test.o sharedmem.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) sharedmem.o -lrt sharedmem_test.o -o sharedmem_test


# Only the tests that REALLY uses UNIX shared memory need the -lrt
checkshm_test :  $(COM_OBJS) checkshm_test.o sharedmem.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(COM_OBJS) sharedmem.o -lrt checkshm_test.o -o checkshm_test


clean :
    /bin/rm -rf *.o *.so *~ midastalker_ex midastalker_ex2 httpserver_ex httpclient_ex midasserver_ex midasyeller_ex midaslistener_ex permutation_server permutation_client load save cxx_repository opal2dict opaltest dict2opal p2_test valgetopt_ex json_ex sharedmem_test ready_test speed_test pickleloader_test chooseser_test xmldump_test xmldump_ex xmlload_test xmlload_ex xml2dict dict2xml samplehttpserver_ex serverside_ex clientside_ex middleside_ex checkshm_test
```

and upon building it using `make -f Makefile.Linux all`, I run into the following error:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -fpic -O -fno-strict-aliasing -DLINUX_ -DOC_NEW_STYLE_INCLUDES -Wno-depr
ecated -I./opencontainers_1_8_5/include -pthread -D_REENTRANT -c m2pythontools.cc
In file included from ./opencontainers_1_8_5/include/ocstreamingpool.h:23,
                 from ./opencontainers_1_8_5/include/ocarray.h:28,
                 from m2pythontools.h:8,
                 from m2pythontools.cc:2:
./opencontainers_1_8_5/include/ocsynchronizer.h:14:10: fatal error: pthread.h: No such fil
e or directory
   14 | #include <pthread.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [MakeFile.Linux:29: m2pythontools.o] Error 1
```

where line 27-30 is:

```
.cc.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

I've checked my `/usr/include` directory and found a `pthread.h` header and there's an ancient [thread](http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/GCC-programming-header-pthread-not-found-but-installed-td11685.html) which mentions that `pthread` is include in `cygwin1.dll` and hence one can simply pass `-lcygwin`. However, that didn't work for me either. I also tried moving the `pthread.h` file into the directory but still got the same error, I don't know how to proceed.

**EDIT:** Running `echo | cpp -v` gives the following output:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\cpp.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-9.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --t
arget=mingw32 --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-stati
c --enable-shared --enable-threads --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --wit
h-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libgomp
 --disable-libvtv --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libs
tdcxx-debug --disable-build-format-warnings --prefix=/mingw --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=
/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --enable-nls --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC B
uild-20200227-1'
Thread model: win32
gcc version 9.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/cc1.exe -E -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../l
ib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/ - -mtune=generic -march=i586
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/
include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../m
ingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include-fixed
End of search list.
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/m
ingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/
../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/..
/../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
```

Comment: Have you installed the [mingw64-x86_64-pthreads](https://www.cygwin.com/packages/summary/mingw64-x86_64-pthreads.html) package?

Comment: yes, specifically it is version number: 20100619-5

Comment: Odd - And if you add `-I/usr/include` when compiling?

Comment: Should I add it in `CCFlags` instead of `-pthread` or add it via a different variable altogether?

Comment: Add it, Don't _replace_ `-pthread` since it will be needed for linking and defining misc stuff.

Comment: Btw, all the makefile macros that you use seem to be the `C` versions, not the `C++` versions. Use `CFLAGS` for the C compiler, `CXXFLAGS` for C++, and `CPPFLAGS` for both. `CC` to specify the `C` compiler and `CXX` to specify the `C++` compiler.

Comment: I changed `CCFLAGS =  -pthread $(CFLAGS)` to `CCFLAGS = -I/usr/include -pthread $(CFLAGS)` and got the same error. Also I've downloaded this makefile from their website, would it make sense to change the relevant flags? [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67294191/cygwin-make-error-specified-module-could-not-be-found/67294432#67294432) a link to the question that I had asked few hours earlier, it shows all the files in the directory, there's no `.c` files, only `.cc`, headers etc.

Comment: I don't know `icc` well, but I think that's the Intel `C` compiler (and `icpc` would be their `C++` compiler) - so it makes sense that _they_ use `C` macros in the makefile. If you are using a `C++` compiler for your project, you should probably also use the `C++` macros for best support. Since it seems to be `C`, you could also use the GNU `C` compiler: `CC = gcc`

Comment: I'm getting the same error, PicklingTools was specifically made for C++, python and Java so I don't know if compiling with `gcc` would do the job, thanks!

Comment: Please run the command `echo | cpp -v` and put the full output into the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo please check out the output in the edit.

Comment: It seems like `pthread.h` doesn't exist in `c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include` (or `c:/mingw/include`), right? I'm not sure if that's a problem with the instalation or not, but you could try `ln -s /usr/include/pthread.h c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include` and compile to see if that changes things.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing cygwin and mingw, they are two totally different systems. Try using only one at a time.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. That sounds a good idea :-) It seems to be the mingw compiler that messes this up.

Comment: I've uninstalled the previous file and since I already had [cygwin-devel](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fcygwin-devel%2Fcygwin-devel-3.2.0-1&grep=pthread) I decided to move forward, the error seems to be the same and the reason likely seems to be because of `fatal error: c:\mingw\lib
\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\pthread.h`. The changes are made in `D:\cygwin64\usr\include` which has `pthread.h` but as you pointed out, initial address doesn't have a `pthread.h` and installing any package using `setup_x86_64` seems to affect the latter address.

Comment: You need to open the cygwin shell and run /usr/bin/gcc from there. Do not try to run c:\mingw\lib when using cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

Depending if you are building for Cygwin or for Mingw (from Cygwin)
you need different cygwin packages: `cygwin-devel` or `mingw64-x86_64-winpthreads`

```
$ cygcheck -l mingw64-x86_64-winpthreads | grep /pthread.h
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/pthread.h

$ cygcheck -l cygwin-devel | grep /pthread.h
/usr/include/pthread.h
```

Comment: Getting rid of `mingw` from Path did the magic, I had `cygwin-devel` while gcc was being run on mingw.